# Error:81115, missing parameter Payment action required?

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

I keep getting Error:81115, missing parameter Payment action required, when i m doing 
Doexpresscheckout method? m sending following parameters

```
&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment
&VERSION=65.1
&PWD=1299156195
&USER=123hel_1299156185_biz_api1.gmail.com
&SIGNATURE=Ai1PaghZh5FmBLCDCTQpwG8jB264Ay4Ll3wOTnzcWtuD-HdE5qiI1p.N+
&TOKEN=EC-6M866117WG376591R
&PAYERID=RDX5GUURFJ9VY
&PAYMENTACTION=%27.Sale
&AMT=104
&CURRENCYCODE=%27USD.%27,
```

help me to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a small search made me found 2 possibles solutions for this :

https://www.x.com/message/157458

http://randomerror.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/error-code-81115-on-paypal-express-checkout-code/

The last one seems to be common in PHP app from paypal:

> mistake on paypalfunctions.php code

```
$token = urlencode($_SESSION['token']);
$paymentType = urlencode($_SESSION['paymentType']);
```

> should be:

```
$token = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
$paymentType = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
```

Comment: Thanks Shikiryu, I tried with above code also but m getting same error.

Comment: Thanks all, I got the solution. It was problem with my return URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
PaymentActionSpecified=true
```

this field should be set...